# Getting RSS with cURL - textContent empty in DomDocument Object

Tags: php, curl, rss

I am working on an multi-rss reader, which basically imports feed from blogs and social media and put them in a timeline. A global social activity report :)

I cant use direct url open on my webserver, so I had to change the script to retrieve the rss feed per curl.

Strange, when I open the rss-feed on local with the load() method, I receive the correct Object. But when I am using cURL to open it, the textContent is empty in the Object. Why this?

Here the code to grab the xml-data

```
foreach ($FeedUrls as $FeedUrl) {
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $FeedUrl['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $rsscurl = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $rss->load($rsscurl);
```

I am getting no curl error with output of curl_error()

The two objects look slight different, I noticed. The

*documentURI* and *baseURI* are filled when not using cURL. But there is no cURL error?

If I print_r the $rsscurl, I see the xml code with the blog posts from the rss feed. But if I print the $rss object after the DOMDocument load, I see the object without the content. ???

What am I missing here?

Comment: rss link ($FeedUrl['url']) is http or https? I think you need process one by one, you foreach to many link is not good!

Comment: its http! thanks, its only 2 links in the foreach, I know this is not a perfect script for many feeds, but I do not think a couple of curl calls should be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aww I found the problem

When loading the rss feed with curl, I have to use the **loadXML()** method instead of load() in the DOMDocument!!

load() loads from file, and loadXML() from string, so the cURL is returning a string, and not a file!

I do not fully understand why I did not get any error on this